# Specifying Webstorm environment from file?

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to specify the environmental variables for Webstorm using, for example, a `.env` file? Where a `.env` file is a file of just key-value pairs like `KEY=value`.

Comment: what variables are meant? the ones you specify in your Run configuration (Node.js, etc.)? No, it's not possible. But you can 'share' your existing run configurations (tick the 'Share' checkbox) to have your configuration saved to your project directory, .idea/runConfigurations/<your_config_name>.xml. So, once you set up the configuration, it can be reused in other projects. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5543